# How to change a default application in Ice Cream Sandwich?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, default-applications

I used the **ADWLauncher EX** by default while having Gingerbread 2.3.6.

Today I have manually updated my Nexus S to **Ice Cream Sandwich 4.0.3**, and I wanted to give the new default launcher a shot, but I cannot find anymore where to select / forget the default application for an action.

I've turned the settings of my phone inside out, googled and crawled the forums, but without success.
If anybody can tell me how to **change a default application** in ICS, I'd be grateful!

---

[image: Android: Complete action using...]

Yeah, I never thought I'd want to see that *Complete action using...* window again! :D

Comment: Doesn't "Clear default in Home Settings > Applications > Manage applications" as suggested in the picture you've posted work in ICS?

Comment: @roxan no, that's exactly the purpose of this question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to Settings, Applications.  Find the app that has the default set.  Scroll down to the bottom of that view and click the "Clear Defaults" button.

[image]

Comment: Bryan, thank you so much! I inadvertently touched my screen and chose a horrible option to launch from a bookmark. I googled and browsed my settings for hours 'till I found this post. What a relief... ... and thank you Marius for asking the question I needed an answer for.

Comment: @MikeSmuts No problem :)

Answer (score 5):

Try [Default App Manager Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appiator.dampro)/[Default App Manager Lite](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.appiator.defaultappmanager). They work superbly and make life a little easier.

Answer (score 4):

If for any reason it seems impossible to clear the default settings, there's a simple work-around available: Simply install another app which offers the same service (e.g. to clear the default launcher setting, install another launcher). The system will detect that another "player" is present, and thus the user might want to chose again -- so next time that activity is requested (in our example: the <kbd>home</kbd> button is pressed), the familiar pop-up will appear again asking to select the app to launch.

Besides: An update of an existing app of the "same group" will trigger this as well (in our example: if one of the installed launchers is updated, the popup will also be triggered next time you hit the <kbd>home</kbd> key).